# Inject different implementions in Controller based on Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ioc-container, lamar

I've got an ASP.NET Core application and I'd like to use different strategies based on the Route selected.
As an example if someone navigates to /fr/Index I want to inject the French translation implementation into my Controller.
Likewise when someone navigates to /de/Index I'd like the German translation injected.

This is to avoid having every single action on my Controller read the "language" parameter and pass it on.

From a higher level, I'd like to have something like that:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Stuff here
    app.MapWhen(
        context => context.Request.Query["language"] == "fr", 
        builder =>
        {
            builder.Register<ILanguage>(FrenchLanguageImplementation);
        });

    app.MapWhen(
        context => context.Request.Query["language"] == "de",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.Register<ILanguage>(GermanLanguageImplementation);
        });
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like I get the IoC container resolving context at that level.

PS: I'm using Lamar as IoC.

Comment: Can you get the value by `context.Request.Query["language"]`?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. That was to illustrate the point. I surely can't call "Register" on the builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`AddScoped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddScoped__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___1__) overload on `IServiceCollection` (or `ServiceRegistry`, which also implements `IServiceCollection`) to provide a factory-based service registration to the DI container. Here's an example implementation of `ConfigureContainer`, with explanatory comments inline:

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services)
{
    // ...

    // Register IHttpContextAccessor for use in the factory implementation below.
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    // Create a scoped registration for ILanguage.
    // The implementation returned from the factory is tied to the incoming request.
    services.AddScoped<ILanguage>(sp =>
    {
        // Grab the current HttpContext via IHttpContextAccessor.
        var httpContext = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
        string requestLanguage = httpContext.Request.Query["language"];

        // Determine which implementation to use for the current request.
        return requestLanguage switch
        {
            "fr" => FrenchLanguageImplementation,
            "de" => GermanLanguageImplementation,
            _ => DefaultLanguageImplementation
        };
    });
}
```

Disclaimer: Up until testing the information in this answer, I've never used Lamar, so this Lamar-specific setup is taken from the docs and a best-guess effort. Without Lamar, the first line in the sample code would be `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` with no other changes.